# Docker image with python & mongodb. Exporting from container to the host

Tags: python, mongodb, docker

I wrote a Python script that analyzes and filters stock data. I write the stock data into a mongodb. The result is a CSV file with the filtered values in it.
Is it now possible to create a docker container that contains Python & mongodb and copies the CSV from the container to the host?

I tried creating a Dockerfile with python only. But when it comes to adding the mongodb service and exporting the file to the host i am a little overstrained.

My goal is that at the end I'll have one Docker container that runs the python script & exports the file to the host.

Do you know any best practice? Or a good tutorial that covers my needs?

Comment: You can copy things *out* of the container using [`docker cp`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/), but a container can't unilaterally export things to the host.

Comment: Best practice is probably to have two containers, one with Python and one with MongoDB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not recommend python and mongodb to be installed on the same docker container. Usually db and the app should be installed on separate containers using docker-compose. But still, if you want them to be on same containers, then you can do so by using an Ubuntu ( or anything else you are comfortable with) image installing mongodb and python on it and then running your scripts. I found this following git repo that contains one such [Dockerfile](https://gist.github.com/jaso514/b7bf419ca9755cc8b24e35c2a993ea47).
Regarding copying CSVs from dockert to host machine, you can do so by using `volumes`, if you want to use docker-compose which I would totally recommend, or you can use `docker cp` command to get the data manually from docker to host.